# How to find smallest numbers in an array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I need to return the smallest numbers (can be more than one) that occur in an array.

```
given [1,1,2,3,3,4]
expected [1,1]

given [8,8,2,3]
expected [2]
```

Comment: examples are clear for me, but what does `that occurs more than once` mean?

Comment: yes I wondered the same, isn't the second example wrong by that statement?

Comment: "To prevent confusion", you should simply say "smallest number".

Comment: @Stefan Hi. How would you word that exactly? I dont mind an edit.

Comment: Why `min(x)` is not possible.?

Comment: @Sylar I'd replace largest / highest with smallest / lowest and it should be clear without further explanation. The fact that you treat `1` as the highest number in your project is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @Зелёный I will not know the value of `n`.

Comment: If you want just the number of such elements: `arr.count { |i| i == arr.min }`

Comment: @sagarpandya82: You could move `arr.min` out of the block to avoid calling it `n` times.

Comment: "To prevent confusion, the smallest number is the highest". Now, that prevented confusion! :)

Comment: @EricDuminil good idea about `arr.min` and agreed about the confusion.

Comment: on second thoughts no need for the block `arr.count(arr.min)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about this?

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4]
min = a.min
a.select { |i| i == min }
 => [1, 1]
```

Comment: I think most would go with this; it's a shame it's not an answer in the question for which this question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

Another way:

```
a = [1,1,2,3,3,4]

a.group_by(&:itself).min.last
```

Comment: Slight variations `a.group_by(&:itself)[a.min]` and `a.group_by(&:itself).fetch(a.min)`

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to solve the problem:

1. Find the smallest number
2. Count how many times it appears
3. Generate an array with the solution instead of selecting elements in the input

Snippet:

```
input = [1,1,2,3,3,4]
highest = input.min
[highest] * input.count(highest)
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* it addresses the question.  Without that, your answer has much less educational value - remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Using this thinking we can do `Array.new(arr.count(arr.min), arr.min)`

Comment: You could, but then you would traverse the array 3 times when 2 suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use `take_while`:

```
sorted = a.sort
sorted.take_while { |e| e == sorted[0] }
=> [1, 1]
```

Other possible way:

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4]
Array.new(*a.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) {|e, acc| acc[e] += 1}.min.reverse)
=> [1, 1]
```